# Python Multithreading for Thread Synchronization

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a question with regards to synchronizing my 2 Python threads below. This is because sometimes, I experience a phenomenon where I get 'corrupted' data written to the CSV file, for example, I am supposed to see 't137' in the CSV file, however, the value that appears in the cell is 't137t137'. My friend mentioned that I should use locks to synchronize my thread but I am not sure which thread locking method I should use.

This is what I am trying to do currently:

Thread 1:

1. Read serial input (sensor values) from 3 Arduino-sensor nodes to a XBee coordinator attached to my computer.
2. Check if all the data has come in successfully, split them into individuals strings to be written to a CSV file.
3. Check for data validity, by averaging the values of the 2 instances immediately before an error occurs. This is because there may be instances where incoming data bunching up.
4. Remove the 't', 'b', 'd' characters.
5. Write data to CSV file.

Thread 2:

1. Perform machine learning tasks to predict an outcome to choose when to turn off/on a light in the room.

(Currently, this thread is just calculating the answer to 8*5 continuously.)

I am confused as to how to use thread locking because I can't see where resources clash, and I am afraid that if I use locking, both threads will not run simultaneously anymore.

May I ask if thread locking is the most appropriate method in this case?

This is my Python code for Thread 1:

```
import threading
import time
import serial
import csv

# Arduino; Arduino is now replaced by XBee modules
arduino = serial.Serial('COM18', 9600, timeout=1)  # Open serial port. By right, should check if it is open

def make_backup(finalmatrix, field_send, flag): # Back up the 2 most-recent data.
    matrix1 = []  # declares a list
    matrix1.append(flag) # appends the counter 'flag'
    matrix1.extend(field_send) # attaches the list to the end of current list; doesn't work with int
    # finalmatrix is a list of list; if len(finalmatrix) == 2 means: finalmatrix == [[1,2], [3,4]]
    if (len(finalmatrix) == 2):
        finalmatrix = finalmatrix[1:] # Create a new list, take the 2nd mini-list in the list and put it in the new list
        finalmatrix.append(matrix1) # appends the new matrix1
    else:
        finalmatrix.append(matrix1)
    return finalmatrix

def acquire_data():
    flag = 1
    finalmatrix = []

    while True:
        # data_in
        try:
            data_in = arduino.readline()  # read serial data from Arduino
        except:
            pass

        global data_stripped
        data_stripped = data_in.strip()  # Removes spaces and \n

        for data_stripped in arduino:
            if data_stripped.startswith('b') and data_stripped.count(
                    ',') == 3:  # first char identifies where data is coming from; count commas to double-check incoming string
                field = data_stripped.split(',')  # split data to be put into 'boxes'
                bed_sen = field[0] + ',' + field[1] + ',' + field[2]  # We have 3 data sensor fields
                bed_sen_fill = True  # A flag to show that this if-statement has been completed

            if data_stripped.startswith('t') and data_stripped.count(',') == 3:
                field = data_stripped.split(',')
                table_sen = field[0] + ',' + field[1] + ',' + field[2]
                table_sen_fill = True

            if data_stripped.startswith('d') and data_stripped.count(',') == 3:
                field = data_stripped.split(',')
                door_sen = field[0] + ',' + field[1] + ',' + field[2]
                door_sen_fill = True

            try:
                if bed_sen_fill == True and table_sen_fill == True and door_sen_fill == True:
                    data_combi = bed_sen + ',' + table_sen + ',' + door_sen
                    break
            except:
                pass

        if data_combi:
            datasplit = data_combi.split(",")
            field1 = datasplit[0]
            field2 = datasplit[1]
            field3 = datasplit[2]
            field4 = datasplit[3]
            field5 = datasplit[4]
            field6 = datasplit[5]
            field7 = datasplit[6]
            field8 = datasplit[7]
            field9 = datasplit[8]

        ##### Data Validity Check #####

        field_send = []  # rearrange into list
        field_send.append(field1)
        field_send.append(field2)
        field_send.append(field3)
        field_send.append(field4)
        field_send.append(field5)
        field_send.append(field6)
        field_send.append(field7)
        field_send.append(field8)
        field_send.append(field9)

        if flag == 1:
            finalmatrix = make_backup(finalmatrix, field_send, flag)
            flag = flag + 1
        else:
            finalmatrix = make_backup(finalmatrix, field_send, flag)
            flag = 1

        print finalmatrix

        if (field1.count('b') == 2 or int(field1_new) > 1000 or not field1):  # If re-sends, 'b' will appear twice; light_val<1000 always.
            field1 = (int(finalmatrix[0][1]) + int(finalmatrix[1][1])) / 2
            print (Error!)

        if (field2.count('-') == 2 or len(field2) > 3 or not field2):  # If re-send, '-' will appear twice; field2 max 3 digits
            field2 = (int(finalmatrix[0][2]) + int(finalmatrix[1][2])) / 2
            print (Error!)

        if (len(field3) > 1 or field3.count('01') == 1 or field3.count('10') == 1 or not field3):  # Motion_sen is binary.
            field3 = (int(finalmatrix[0][3]) + int(finalmatrix[1][3])) / 2
            print (Error!)

        if (field4.count('t') == 2 or int(field4_new) > 1000 or not field4):  # If re-sends, 't' will appear twice; light_val<1000 always.
            field4 = (int(finalmatrix[0][4]) + int(finalmatrix[1][4])) / 2
            print (Error!)

        if (field5.count('-') == 2 or len(
            field5) > 3 or not field5):  # If re-send, '-' will appear twice; field5 max 3 digits
            field5 = (int(finalmatrix[0][5]) + int(finalmatrix[1][5])) / 2
            print (Error!)

        if (len(field6) > 1 or field6.count('01') == 1 or field6.count('10') == 1 or not field6):  # Motion_sen is binary.
            field6 = (int(finalmatrix[0][6]) + int(finalmatrix[1][6])) / 2
            print (Error!)

        if (len(field8) > 1 or field8.count('01') == 1 or field8.count('10') == 1 or not field8):  # Motion_sen is binary.
            field8 = (int(finalmatrix[0][8]) + int(finalmatrix[1][8])) / 2
            print (Error!)

         if (len(field9) > 1 or field9.count('01') == 1 or field9.count('10') == 1 or not field9):  # SW is binary too!
            field9 = (int(finalmatrix[0][9]) + int(finalmatrix[1][9])) / 2
            print (Error!)

        field1 = field1.replace('b','')
        field4 = field4.replace('t','')

        with open('abs_testdata.csv', 'ab') as csvfile:  # 'ab' to remove newline char after each print
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            sensor_fields = [field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9,
                             time.strftime("%H%M%S")]
            writer.writerow(sensor_fields)

        time.sleep(1)
```

Python code for Thread 2:

```
def counting():
     while True:
         sum = 3 + 2
         sum2 = sum*8
         print sum2
         time.sleep(0.2)
```

Python code for main thread:

```
def on_light():
    strin = '1'
    arduino.write(strin.encode())
    print "Confirm ON"

def off_light():
    strin = '0'
    arduino.write(strin.encode())
    print "Confirm OFF"

# now threading1 runs regardless of user input
threading1 = threading.Thread(target = acquire_data)
threading2 = threading.Thread(target = counting)
threading1.start()
threading2.start()

while True:
    if raw_input() == 't':
        on_light()
        print "ON"
    if raw_input() == 'r':
        off_light()
        print "OFF"

    time.sleep(1)
```

Thank you! :):)

Comment: This code writes to CSV from Thread1 only. The corrupted values in CSV are is not because of a synchronization issue

Comment: @Marat Thank you for your reply. May I ask if you meant that, because I am writing to CSV from Thread1 only, I will face the problem of synchronization issues? Thank you! (:

Comment: no, I mean exactly the opposite. Since there is no concurrent writing/reading, it is NOT a synchronization issue. There is definitely an error in the code forming the data in Thread 1. Even if there were no threads at all, you would still have this issue. Please debug your code (perhaps single thread) first.

Comment: @Marat I see. I am sorry for misunderstanding your words. This issue did not happen in the past when I ran it with a single thread, hence I thought it was an issue with the locking/synchronization of the threads. I have a feeling that it may be a fault due to one of my Arduino nodes as I have changed its code so that it could capture incoming signals at any time. May I ask if it would help if I were to post the Arduino code above? Thank you! :)

Comment: something as simple as logging arduino communication with `logging.warning(data_in)` will be sufficient to check if the error is in the arduino code.

Comment: @Marat Thank you so much for your help! :) As I am new to Arduino, I will read up on the function and hopefully, try it tonight! :) I will update you again on the results. (:

Comment: @Marat May I ask if I am correct to say this? The logging.warning(data_in) will log the event "data_in", and I have to observe how data streams in from Arduino (i.e. the fashion in which data streams into Arduino) to identify the errors. Am I right to say this? :)

Comment: [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) will just print the data. If you see the anomalous string in the output (i.e. something not matching /[btd]\d+/, e.g. "t137t137"), then the problem is in Arduino code (perhaps missing comma)

Comment: @Marat I have a feeling that it is a communications issue which didn't occur before but is happening now, strangely. >< In the printout, it read: "WARNING:root:b438,t622,54,0,

WARNING:root:-1,0,"
By right, each node should send out only 3 blocks of data, i.e. "A, B, C,", and sometimes, the above happens (for all other times, the transmission is fine) randomly. May I ask if it is due to a fault on the Arduino?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the problem is in the code executed on Arduino

Comment: @Marat Thank you for your kind advice. :) May I ask if it would be helpful if I were to post my Arduino codes above? I have a feeling that the error is caused by one of the 3 Arduino nodes in my network. Thank you so much for your advice once again.

Comment: I'm not really an Arduino person, and, what is more important, questions "why this code is not working" are considered off-topic on StackOverflow. I would suggest debugging this code yourself and posting another question with a specific problem.

Comment: @Marat I see. Thank you so much for your advice. I will try to debug the code myself. I asked because I wanted to confirm my suspicion about one thing in my Arduino code, but I guess I will try to debug first before asking :) Thank you once again and have a great day and week ahead! :)